# Cloak and Dagger, what's the catch?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

Cloak and dagger has 100% generation rate, besides you remain half-invisible even if the cloak is depleted. This looks like it has lots of advantages over Invisibility Watch but not any shortcomings. But there has to be some. Can someone tell me what they are?

And considering these disadvantages what is the best situation to use it instead of regular Invisibility Watch?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A few disadvantages:

1. It has less overall cloak time than the Invisibility Watch if you're running (6.6s vs. 9s).
2. Whilst cloaked, you cannot use ammo boxes or dropped weapons to recharge your cloak, you must decloak to pick them up. With the Invisibility Watch, you can pick them up under full cloak.

Comment: The ammo crate one is a log bigger than it sounds at first glance.  A spy who knows his surroundings with the standard invisibility watch can stay invisible just as well as a spy with Cloak and Dagger.

Comment: Not to mention that even dropped weapons will refill the standard invisibility watch, meaning you can immediately regain some cloak after a successful backstab by picking up the foe's dropped weapon.

Answer (score 8):

The important stats on the three watches are:

### Invisibility Watch:

- **9 seconds** Cloak Time
- Charge time (to full): 33.5s
- Recharges 25%, 50%, 100% from small, medium/weapon, and large ammo boxes respectively.
- You appear as a team-colored silhouette when an enemy player or weapon hits you.

### Cloak and Dagger:

- **6.6 seconds** Cloak Time (assuming you're moving the entire time)
- Charge time (to full): 15.3s
- Recharges while standing still (cloaked).
- You appear as a team-colored silhouette when an enemy player or weapon hits you.
- Rather than decloaking, you appear as a team-colored silhouette if you move when the meter has run out.

### Dead Ringer:

- **6.5 seconds** Cloak Time
- Charge time (to full): 16s
- Recharges 25%, 40%, 40% from small, medium/weapon, and large ammo boxes respectively.
- Does not cloak when activated, but the first time you take damage after activation (right-clicking again before being hit will put it back away).
- "Perfect" cloak for the first 6.5s.  After that, you appear as a team-colored silhouette when an enemy player or weapon hits you.
- Can only be used at 100% cloak.
- Decloaking at > 40% cloak remaining reduces cloak meter to 40%.
- Louder decloak sound

Answer (score 1):

It does have slightly less charge, but I personally wouldn't go back to the standard watch - the Cloak & Dagger has saved me too many times where I would stand still and people just walked on by.

The less overall cloak can be mitigated if you stand still.

Answer (score 0):

> Considering these disadvantages what is the best situation to use it
>   instead of regular Invisibility Watch?

I personnaly use it when the ennemy team is concentrated in one point with lots of engineers and when you just can't go in there non-cloaked without dying, even with a disguise.
In Capture the Flag for example, if the other team is camping their flag and defending their base a lot, it's a good choice.
You'll probably have to stop several times halfway to replenish invisibility before reaching your goal but once you're in the ennemy base, behind their defense lines, with the Cloak and Dagger, then you can start having fun.

**Protip** : if people are starting to chase and look for you, just get invisible and climb on the top of a box or any other prop in the map. People NEVER look up to spycheck. Just stay here as long as you need while invisible and get back to the business when they start forgetting you !

I usually play the CoD with Your eternal recompense, it's a great combo to destroy a base from the inside.